# Function to compare 2 values in excel, if the difference is less than 4, change both values to average of 2

Tags: excel, function

My list has 3 columns.  An ID, line start value and line end value of a line segment.  I need a function statement that if the ID is the same for row 1 and row 2 it will subtract the start value of row 2 from the end value of row 1. If the difference is less than 4, it needs to find the average of the 2 numbers and change both values to that average.  I have to do this for 1000s of rows at a time.  I created a sample below.  I know how to make it check to see if the IDs of the 2 rows match.

```
Original Table:                           Result:
ID      Start       Stop                 ID      Start     Stop
A        0.4         2.6                 A        0.4       **2.6**
A        2.7         4.5                 A        **2.6**       4.5
A        10          11.5                A        10        11.5
B        0           1.5                 B        0         **3.2**
B        5           7.5                 B        **3.2**       7.5
B        8           10                  B        8         10
C        11.4        11.9                C        11.4      11.9
```

Comment: Providing requirements without showing any effort was once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is still [being debated now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic), and many people consider it to be rude.

Comment: I'm not understanding what it is you're asking to do... What are the `**`s for? What would the expected results for your sample be?

Comment: Thanks, @pnuts... I didn't get that at all!! - I editied the Q to show that A BIT better...

Answer (score 0):

If `0.4` is in B2, then Copy ColumnA to ColumnE, B1:C1 to F1 and in F2:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,IF(B2-C1<4,(B2+C1)/2,B2),B2),1)
```

and in G2:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(IF(AND(MOD(ROW(),3)=2,B3-C2<4),(B3+C2)/2,C2),1)
```

and copy both formulae down to suit.